# Oracle SQL - Pivot table count and with column might grow dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have this table in Oracle 18c:

```
+-----------+------------+------------------+
|    ID     |  Rule 1    | Rule 2  | Rule 3 |
+-----------+------------+------------------+
| ID001     | PASSED     | FAILED  | PASSED |
| ID002     | FAILED     | FAILED  | FAILED |
| ID003     | FAILED     | PASSED  | PASSED |
| ID004     | FAILED     | PASSED  | PASSED |
| ID005     | FAILED     | PASSED  | FAILED |
| ID006     | FAILED     | PASSED  | PASSED |
| ID007     | FAILED     | PASSED  | FAILED |
| ID008     | FAILED     | PASSED  | PASSED |
| ID009     | FAILED     | PASSED  | FAILED |
| ID010     | FAILED     | PASSED  | FAILED |
+-----------+------------+---------+--------+
```

I wanted to transform it to have counted of each failed / passed rules based on ID count

expected result as below :

```
+-----------+---------------------+
|   Rules   |  PASSED    | FAILED |
+-----------+---------------------+
| Rule 1    | 1          | 10     |
| Rule 2    | 8          | 2      |
| Rule 3    | 5          | 5      |
+-----------+------------+--------+
```

Also another problem is, **the table might grow in future (more column added)**, and the query should be able to handle it without any changes.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Fix your data model!  You are storing data in columns that should be in different rows.

Comment: I really wish I can do that, but that's not an option for now...

Comment: . . Adding new columns to the table changes the data model.

Comment: Does it have to be a single SQL statement?  Normally, if you want the pivot to be dynamic, you'd create a bit of PL/SQL that dynamically created the pivot query.

Comment: no it does not have to be single a SQL statement...

Answer (score 0):

You could use pivot, group by the rule and count the sum for PASSED and FAILED like this:

```sql
select rules,
   sum(case when result = 'PASSED' then 1 else 0 end) PASSED,
   sum(case when result = 'FAILED' then 1 else 0 end) FAILED
from (
select * from yourTable
UNPIVOT(
  result
  FOR rules
  IN (
   "Rule 1" AS 'Rule 1',
   "Rule 2" AS 'Rule 2'
  )
))
group by rules;
```